# Mandelbrot Set Fractal

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, community-challenge, fractals

I thought I would give this months [community challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5998/81229) a try. This is my first time using Python.
It does take quite a while to run and it's not very colourful but it works.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new("RGB", (2400, 2400), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

max_count = 200
width = img.size[0]
height = img.size[1]

for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        str_output = ""
        c = complex(
            (col - float(width)/2.0)*5.0/float(width),
            (row - float(height)/2.0)*5.0/float(height)
        )
        iteration = 0
        z = 0
        while abs(z) < 2 and iteration < max_count:
            z = z**2 + c
            iteration += 1
        if abs(z) < 2:
            draw.point((col, row), fill="black")
        else:
            draw.point((col, row), fill=(255 - iteration,255 - iteration,255 - iteration))

img.save('mandelbrot.png')
```

[image: black and white mandelbrot set]

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan 3.whatever_the_latest_release_is

Comment: @JamesFenwick That would be 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constants should be in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE

```
MAX_COUNT = 200
WIDTH = img.size[0]
HEIGHT = img.size[1]
```

Instead of nested for loops, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which basically will perform the nested iteration you need:

```
from itertools import product

for row, col in product(range(height), range(width))
```

You don't use `str_output`, you should clean up unused values.

You should have whitespace either side of your mathematical operators and have a space after each comma in a comma separated list of values:

```
(col - float(width) / 2.0) * 5.0 / float(width),
draw.point((col, row), fill=(255 - iteration, 255 - iteration, 255 - iteration))
```

You should also keep lines below 79 characters as the Python style guide dictates. You can split lines quite easily when they're in paretheses:

```
    draw.point((col, row), fill=(255 - iteration, 255 - iteration,
                                 255 - iteration))
```

Also your mileage may vary on whether or not this is more readable but you could use a ternary for your final `if` condition. Like this:

```
    draw.point((col, row), fill=("black" if abs(z) < 2 else 
                                 (255 - iteration, 255 - iteration,
                                  255 - iteration))
```

The formatting is definitely more awkward, but I personally like these structures because it makes it clear that the only difference in the two results is that one condition.

Answer (score 2):

- This feels a bit backwards to me

  ```
  img = Image.new("RGB", (2400, 2400), "white")
  width = img.size[0]
  height = img.size[1]
  ```

  compared to this

  ```
  WIDTH = 2400
  HEIGHT = 2400
  img = Image.new("RGB", (WIDTH, HEIGHT), "white")
  ```
- You can eliminate all the `float` calls because you are using Python 3 where true division is the default.
- `for` loops are generally preferred over `while` loops. A possible way to arrange the inner loop is this:

  ```
  z = 0
  for iteration in range(MAX_COUNT):
      z = z**2 + c
      if abs(z) >= 2:
          fill = (255 - iteration, 255 - iteration, 255 - iteration)
          break
  else:
      fill="black"
  draw.point((col, row), fill=fill)
  ```